# about python pig latin. preserving Capitalization and keep "qu" together

Tags: python

one of my assignment requires following condition.
"Extend it further to preserve capitalization, and to keep qu together (i.e. so that quiet becomes ietquay). "

so It means, if you have words like "Quiet", it should be like "Ietqu"

- my teacher's definition of PIG latin is that, starting with vowel -> add "ay" in the end / starting with consonants -> move the cluster of consonants(the consonants cluster before first vowel) to the end and add "ay"

I tried to find the index of "QU" in words, and then using this index I tried to make code  but there are so many cases I should consider...

how will u make codes for solving that assignment..?

Comment: show your code that works without considering qu.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list of all possible words that start with "Qu' is really going about this the wrong way.

Trying searching the first index([0]) of the string for "q" if it finds q, it will almost certainly also find u, but just to make sure, also check for u if q is found. Then simply recreate the string with the new value. So let's use this as a quick example:

```
testInput = raw_input("Enter a word to be piglatinized!")

if testInput[0].lower() == "q":
    if testInput[1].lower() == "u":
        print testInput[2:]+testInput[0:2]+"ay"
    else:
        print testInput[1:]+testInput[0:1] + "ay"
else:
    print testInput[1:]+testInput[0:1] + "ay"
```